# Getting Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

I am calling a ssrs report from the .net application with adding the report viewer. But i trying to opening the report it is showing attached error. can any one help on this. The error is coming from ScriptResource.axd file.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There may be problem of your session. There is a very good link about this on MSDN.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/selvar/archive/2012/10/16/reportviewer-control-fails-with-sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerservererrorexception-failed-to-load-viewstate.aspx

Also please go through this forum discussion also.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9c86dd4f-478c-439f-98b1-821e1bf91a3a/reportviewer-syswebformspagerequestmanagerservererrorexception